# iPhone 4 Custom SMS Text Tones

Tags: iphone, sms, ringtones

I read about how to add custom ring tones, but those don't show up in the SMS tone tab, just the phone ring tab, is there some way to add custom text tones without jailbreaking my iPhone? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are new SMS tones as of 4.2, and you can assign a specific SMS tone to a specific person via the Contacts app also as of 4.2, but you still cannot create custom SMS tones in the stock firmware.

Comment: Is there any hint as to when custom SMS tones will be possible?

Comment: It won't happen until it happens. :) I have absolutely no idea when it might/if it might. E-mail sjobs@apple.com? I think that's his current address. I suggest looking around first before sending mail there. Other people seem to be having pretty good success with that.